# How do I properly seal gaps along my foundation?

Tags: foundation

My home is about 6 years old and I noticed that at some points there is a gap between the foundation and sill plate. What should be used to seal it and should it be done on the inside, outside, or both?

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is a pour stop around the concrete and the concrete has shrunk away from the pour stop (usually a fabric joint filler). You can use a utility knife to trim down the filler material (about 1/2") then fill the gap with a flexible sealant. You might have to chip out the concrete for ease of cutting.